# Jquery compatibility with Android Apps

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview, bootstrap-modal

In my Android app, I have a Webview and an html file(html tags + javascript code) is loaded in this Webview. That .html file includes jquery(v2.1.3) and bootstrap(v3.3.7) scripts. Though Webview works fine on Android devices with Lollipop installed in them, it is not working for devices with Kitkat or JellyBean installed on them. 
Ex- html list Items aren't clickable in older versions.

I couldn't find anywhere data on compatibility between jQuery,bootstrap and Android Webview. Can someone please help?
The minimum SDK version for the app is 16.

Answer (score 0):

KitKat's WebView is a mess. (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/1ZxXe6chHZc) It's because canvas hardware acceleration is not enabled in the underlying chromium component.

Few guys were successful by invoking

`mWebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Comment: Didn't work for me. For me it's not even working for JellyBean.